# Does covariate must be observed variable?

Tags: repeated-measures, predictor

In my study, I found significant interactions between treatment and order of sessions. Can I put the order variable as covariate in order to control this effect?

Comment: The title suggests you did not "observe" the order.  If you don't have the order information, then you cannot use it as a covariate; but if you do have the order information, then it's an observation--it's information available to you.  What might be of greater concern is whether the order is meaningful and generalizable: for instance, if you intend to make inferences to future treatments where there won't be the same number or spacing of sessions, then perhaps you will be unable to use the "order" for this purpose. Could you provide a little more information about your objectives?

Comment: Hi! I counterbalanced the order of session,, so this information is available. Unfortunately, despite the counterbalance, there is a significant interaction between the order and the treatment. My question is: Can I "control" the effects of order by entering the order variable as a covariate?

Comment: I randomly assigned participants into two orders: 
The first group received the intervention in the first session and the placebo in the second session, while the second group received the intervention in the second session and the placebo in the second session.
I found significant interaction between treatment and order: the first group scored higher in the intervention, and the second group scored higher in the placebo.